# when run php project in eclipse "Couldn't connect to Server"

Tags: php, eclipse, eclipse-pdt

I want to run my first php project in eclipse(with help of pet package). When I run my project (index.php) eclipse show an error with below message :

```
Page Login failed with error. Could not connect to the server.
```

More information :

- When I enter "http ://localhost" in my browser it couldn't find server
- I'm using kepler version of eclipse
- I'm run eclipse in MAC OSX

I think my local server didn't start or I haven't local server. How can I solve this error? How can run local php server in mac ?

Best Regards

Comment: You have to install and configure a local http server. Use the apache http server for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install a server package, something like [MAMP](https://www.mamp.info). Then you need to configure it in order to be driven by Eclipse, using Xdebug, which is a module for Apache. In order to set up your configuration with Xdebug, take a look here: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Debugging_using_XDebug